# Inequality relation between Mean, Mode and RMS value of the Speed Distribution

Tags: statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

In the following question, we have to find inequality relations between Average, Peak and RMS values of the Speed Distribution. Now we know that Average is always less than RMS for non-equal distribution. Also, by looking at the skew in the graph, it is clear that Peak is larger than the Average. My question is how do we definitely decide inequality between Peak and RMS values?

[image]

Comment: One thought is that the RMS is related to the average of $v^2 N(\nu)$. I suspect the tail after the peak of $N(\nu)$ is meant to be falling off faster than $\nu^{-2}$.

Comment: *My question is how do we definitely decide inequality between Peak and RMS values?* In general I do not think this is possible.